# No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts (injectionError)

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error when using Angular CLI to generate a routing module for my application:

```
ERROR Error: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9481)
    at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10569)
    at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11072)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10936)
```

I generated the routing module with Angular CLI like this:

```
ng generate module --routing App
```

This is the contents of the routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And this is what I have in my `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="container" role="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: is this lazy loaded module?

Comment: no, eagerly loaded, it's actually the main module of the app.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

To solve this problem change this line:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
```

to:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
```

The error is caused because `RouterModule.forChild()` generates a module that contains the necessary directives and routes but **doesn't include the routing service**. That is what `RouterModule.forRoot` is for: it generates a module that contains the necessary directives, routes, *and* the routing service.

More information in Angular docs: [Angular - Router Module](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#how-to-use).

Comment: I put `RouterModule.forRoot([]),` in my app.module, then I put `RouterModule.forChild([]),` in my app-routing.module, this did it for me.

Answer (score 13):

This is usually happen to me when I didn't import the correct `routing` module.

For e.g: Inside `AppModule` I imported
`RouterModule` from '@angular/router' by mistake
instead of `AppRoutingModule` from './app-routing.module'

When i'm working with the Angular CLI I trust the compiler so I double check my self and in most cases it was my bad
so when it comes to generating routing files along with the module i'm positive that Angular team are doing it good

Answer (score 2):

> imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]

Change this line in RoutingModuleclass

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For info it would be useful if you can add some context for the OP as to why they need to change this and what it will do compared to what they currently have, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also:

I have created a `route` file to separate all routings.

**Import your routes into your module like this:**

**app.route.ts:**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/homeComponent/home.component';
import { ListComponent } from './components/listComponent/list.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
    { path: '', component: ListComponent },
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Now in `app.module.ts` you have to import the `routing`:

```
import { routing } from './app.route';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    routing,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It works for me.