# Error: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can not make use of angular/material with Angular 5 in any way.
I followed this [simple Tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/113/How-to-Build-an-Angular-5-Material-App), but whenever I insert some material tag in component HTML, the web page gets blank.

Angular CLI does not show any issues when using `ng serve`

**Dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<button mat-button>My Button</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**material.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  exports: [MatButtonModule],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Console Window Error:**

[image: Browser console errors]

Comment: any issue in browser's console window?

Comment: thanks for reminding, question is updated

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**The error is completely unrelated to the material modules.**

Two things need to be done before using the `<router-outlet>` directive:

1. Import the `RouterModule` (or any of the "versions" of it
   generated by `forRoot` or `forChildren` methods) into the module
   that **declares** components that use the directive.
2. The `forRoot` method of the `RouterModule` has to be called. Otherwise the services required by the directive wont be initialized.

So basically, change the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As mentioned by other user, you haven't really configured any routes, so the use of `<router-outlet>` isn't necessary.

This is basically a dup of [No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts (injectionError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108581/no-provider-for-childrenoutletcontexts-injectionerror) (found it by searching the error message in google, 1st result). For a next time do some research before creating a question.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is not with **`Angular-material`** but with **`RouterModule`**. Import it and add it into `imports` array.

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    RouterModule,                   //<=======add RouterModule

    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: did not work, question is updated

Comment: Are you having multiple routes seriously or you just use `router-outlet` in html ?

Comment: I am a beginner in Angular, I was just following the demo

Comment: If, as of now, you are not using Routers, would suggest you to get rid of `router-outlet` tag from the HTML. That should resolve the problem.

Comment: yes, thank you, it did