# NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, stackblitz

I'm still learning angular. I was trying to create an example on stackblitz to ask another question and ran into an issue with routing.

I'm trying to set up routing. I have added the following to app.module.ts:

```
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  FormsModule,
                  RouterModule,
```

and then I created app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NavComponent } from './components/NavComponent';
import { SearchComponent } from './components/SearchComponent';
import { ViewComponent } from './components/ViewComponent';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/nav', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'nav', component: NavComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'view', component: ViewComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and then added these imports to app.module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

I thought that was all I needed to do, but when I load my app, I get:

```
ERROR
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!
```

I googled this error and found: [No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts (injectionError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108581/no-provider-for-childrenoutletcontexts-injectionerror) and [Error: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606310/error-no-provider-for-childrenoutletcontexts/47607830) but I don't find these helpful.

Here is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1seie?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts.

No idea where to go next.

Comment: Replace `RouterModule` with `AppRoutingModule` in your app module imports array.

Comment: @R.Richards That seems to have done it. Do you want to create an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to replace `RouterModule` with `AppRoutingModule` in your app module imports array. Without that the application doesn't know about the routes you've configured. Easy enough to miss if this is new to you.