# Angular 5 Router Module No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts! error

Tags: angular, routes, router, angular5

I am working on the part of routing in my Angular 5 project.

I did the following:

1. I created a new routes module called `routes.module.ts`:

   `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`

   `import { UdemyComponent } from './udemy/udemy.component';`

   `const appRoutes: Routes = [
       {path: 'udemy', component: UdemyComponent}
   ];`

   `@NgModule({
       imports: [
           RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true})//<--Debugging purposes only)
       ]
   });`

   `export class RouteModule {}`
2. In the `app.module.ts`:

   `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`

   `import { RouteModule } from './routes.module';`

   ```
   imports: [
   BrowserModule,

   ReactiveFormsModule,

   HttpClientModule,

   RouterModule
   ],
   ```
3. I added the following in my app.component.ts:

And finally, I've got the following error:

> AppComponent.html:59 ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError[ChildrenOutletContexts]:
>   StaticInjectorError[ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!
>       at *NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
>       at NgModuleRef*.get (core.js:12110)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:12608)

After a few searches I found this [link on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108581/no-provider-for-childrenoutletcontexts-injectionerror?answertab=votes#tab-top). So I changed my imports in `app.module.ts` imports into:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(RouteModule)
],
```

So I've got the following error:

> Error: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be
>   provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

So I changed my route file into:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UdemyComponent } from './udemy/udemy.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'udemy', component: UdemyComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo:'/', component: AppComponent},
    {path: '**', component: AppComponent}
];
```

But the error didn't gone.

I don't know why my code is not formatted correctly so I hope the admins can edit it.

Comment: import "RouteModule" missing in app module

Comment: No it is added in `app.module.ts`, check it. It is already in it.

Comment: nope , you have included "RouterModule" not "RouteModule"

Comment: @PrasanthS Sir, check step number 2. It is already there. I added the both lines.

Comment: include into this " imports: [
BrowserModule,

ReactiveFormsModule,

HttpClientModule,

RouterModule
],

Comment: hope now you got it

Comment: Okay but I've got the following error now `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'RouteModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'.`

Comment: let me add the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
routes ts file:
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UdemyComponent } from './udemy/udemy.component';

//you need to export the route to known to app module

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'udemy', component: UdemyComponent}
];

In app module ts file

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes} from './app.routes';

imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
 ],
```

Comment: No errors but nothing happens when I click on a page to take to Udemy component

Comment: how you are linking

Answer (score 1):

The route `''` has both `redirectTo` and `component` attributes, but must have only one of them.
Remove the `component` or `redirectTo` attribute depending that you want.

```
{path: '', redirectTo:'/'},
```

or

```
{path: '', component: AppComponent},
```